# Creating a loop to use read.eset in bioconductor

Tags: r, loops, input, bioconductor

I would like to create a loop to load this files through `read.eset`of bioconductor.
I tried that:

```
for(k in 1:29){
  expr <- paste0("/home/proj/MT_Nellore/R/eBrowser/Adjusted/LRRadjustedextremes0.5kgchr",k,".txt")
  pdat <- paste0("/home/proj/MT_Nellore/R/eBrowser/Adjusted/Samplesbinary0.5.txt")
  ffdat <- paste0("/home/proj/MT_Nellore/R/LRR/Chr_adjusted/probeslabeladjustedchr",k,".txt")
  eset <- read.eset(exprs.file="expr", pdat.file="/home/proj/MT_Nellore/R/eBrowser/Adjusted/Samplesbinary0.5.txt", fdat.file="ffdat")
 }
```

However I get this error:

```
## Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
## In addition: Warning message:
## In file(file, "r") : cannot open file 'ffdat': No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you get the error, find out the value of k, and check that the relevant the relevant file exists with `dir("/home/proj/MT_Nellore/R/LRR/"`)

Comment: I guess that all files: probeslabeladjustedchr1.txt, probeslabeladjustedchr2.txt ... probeslabeladjustedchr29.txt are inside `dir("/home/proj/MT_Nellore/R/LRR/Chr_adjusted/")`. My concern is if the syntax in my script are correct...

Comment: Ah - just spotted the error - you must remove quotes from around the "ffdat" on the final line, and same for the "expr"

Comment: Yes, I get it just modifying this line as you told..

`eset <- read.eset(exprs.file=expr, pdat.file=pdat, fdat.file=ffdat)`

But I put 4 more lines:

`data <- fData(eset) outfile <- paste0("chr",k,"FCadjusted.txt") setwd("/home/proj/MT_Nellore/R/eBrowser/Adjusted/FC") write.table(data, outfile, quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)}}`

And now the problem is that just files 1 to 8 were writed... Why files 9 until 29 cannot be written?

Comment: Do you get an error - or do they just not appear?

Comment: Just do not appear. I get my expected files just until k==8.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51656/discussion-between-gavin-kelly-and-user3091668)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - just spotted the error - you must remove quotes from around the "ffdat" on the final line, and same for the "expr"